# Alternatives for running a map-reduce jar in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I know that the `hadoop jar` command is used to run a Map-Reduce jar in Hadoop, but there is this `setJar(String jar)` [method](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setJar(java.lang.String)) in the `Job` class of the Map-Reduce API. This page of the API [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setJar(java.lang.String)) mentions `Jar` as a parameter to the Job class.

Hence I was wondering if there is any way to run the jar file other than `hadoop jar`, and what is role of this setJar() method.

Any help would be great. 
TIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally hadoop tried to find job jar, to do that your job’s classes must be packaged into a job JAR. So setJar() and setJarByClass() does that nothing else.

See from [Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, 4th Edition by Tom White](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hadoop-the-definitive/9781491901687/ch06.html)

> For a start, a job’s classes must be packaged into a job JAR file to send to the cluster. Hadoop will find the job JAR automatically by searching for the JAR on the driver’s classpath that contains the class set in the setJarByClass() method (on JobConf or Job). Alternatively, if you want to set an explicit JAR file by its file path, you can use the setJar() method. (The JAR file path may be local or an HDFS file path.)